# Find Constant Variable P(x)

Tags: polynomials

if polynomials P(x)= ($x^2$ +2)Q(x+4), and if polynomials Q(x) divided by (x-1) remains 5, then the constant of P(x)?

i have try to find the Q(x) but i don't still get it, what i have to do first to find constant of P(x)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you provide us with some context about this question with an [edit]? Where does this problem com from? What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far, and where did that fail? Do you know how to perform polynomial division?

Comment: yes, i tried to find Q(x+4) first by P(x) divided by ($x^2$+2)

Comment: When adding clarification that is essential to the post, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.